# Javascript: Input the duration of movie and return number of hours

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

I'm new to react and as practise, I'm building a react app. The form has a duration input which expects the data either in minutes or hours eg. 132m or 2.5h. The function should return the number of hours based on the input or show error in alert that "Duration is in invalid format".

How can I go about this? The value is string and so I was thinking of using `duration.includes('m')` or  `duration.includes('h')` but the problem is it will accept "1h32" for example. I also want to know how float can be extracted from the string?

Comment: How is the form being controlled as of now? Can any character be inputted?  How you are guiding the user to use either a minutes or hours format?  It would be nice to see your current ````event handler```` so we have something to go off of.

Comment: You can either use Regex to ensure correct format. Or you can also create one input component on UI for inputting the number and another combobox for selecting between h or m.

Comment: Could not agree more with @GiorgiMoniava. The second option which is having two separate inputs for value and unit is probably the simpler, less error prone, most extendable and probably even most user-friendly way to go about it, though.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Can you provide a rough snippet maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a regular expression to parse the numbers from the given input. Next, you have to convert the strings to a number.
Last, pass the result to a calculate function to convert minutes to hours

```js
const input = '132m';
// const input = '2.5h'
// const input = '1h32';

function parseDuration(input) {
  const { groups } = input.match(/((?<hours>\d+(\.\d+)?)h)?((?<minutes>\d+)m?)?/);

  const hours = Number(groups.hours) || 0;
  const minutes = Number(groups.minutes) || 0;

  return {
    hours,
    minutes,
  };
}

function durationToHours(hours, minutes) {
  return hours + minutes / 60;
}

const parsedDuration = parseDuration(input);
const hours = durationToHours(parsedDuration.hours, parsedDuration.minutes);

hours; // 2.2
```